# Id is not getting when page is reloaded using useParams()

Tags: reactjs

snapshots are given below... when the page is reloaded id is not getting using useParams()

Source Code
[image]

Error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should access them from the useEffect (after the first render)